# Wordpress Insert not working with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, query, mysql, wpdb

I am trying to enter insert data with form in wordpress and want to use ajax for that. Without ajax it works fine but when I use ajax pressing the submit button gives 0 in result and the data is not inserted to the database . Below is my code.

Html code is between form tags as below

```
<form id="insertform" action="" method="post">
<input id="user" style="height: 30px;" name="user" type="text" />
.
.
.
<button id="Submit" type="submit">SUBMIT </button>
</form>
```

php code

```
function wp_insert(){
if(isset($_POST['skillname'])!= '' && $_POST['Address']!= ''){
    $user_info = wp_get_current_user();
$username=$user_info->user_login;
//insert to database

If($_POST['Submit']) {

// run validation if you're not doing it in js
global $wpdb;

//assigning textbox values to variables

$yourname=$_POST['user'];
$lat=$_POST['latitude'];
$long=$_POST['longitude'];
$address=$_POST['Address'];
$city=$_POST['City'];
$state=$_POST['State'];
$country=$_POST['Country'];
$zip=$_POST['zipcode'];
$skillname=$_POST['skillname'];
$yourself=$_POST['yourself'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];


if($wpdb->insert(
        'wp_store_locator',
        array(
                'secretcode' =>$username,
                'sl_description' => $yourname,
                'sl_latitude' => $lat,
                'sl_longitude' => $long,
                'sl_address' => $address,
                'sl_city' => $city,
                'sl_state' => $state,
                'sl_country' => $country,
                'sl_zip' => $zip,
                'sl_store' => $skillname,
                'yourself' => $yourself,
                'sl_email' => $email,
                'sl_phone' => $phone )) == false) wp_die('Database Insertion failed'); else echo 'Database insertion successful'; exit();

}

}

}//end of function
```

Enqueue code for Jquery

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_insert' ); 

function add_insert(){  

add_action( 'wp_ajax_wp_insert', 'wp_insert' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wp_insert', 'wp_insert');
// register & enqueue a javascript file called globals.js
wp_register_script( 'globalss', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/ajaxinsert.js", array( 'jquery' ) ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'globalss' );

// use wp_localize_script to pass PHP variables into javascript
wp_localize_script( 'globalss', 'yess', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
```

Jquery File ajaxinsert.js

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#insertform").submit(function (e) { //form is intercepted
        e.preventDefault();

        //serialize the form which contains secretcode
        var sentdataa = $(this).serializeArray();

        //Add the additional param to the data        
        sentdataa.push({
            name: 'action',
            value: 'wp_insert'
        })

        //set sentdata as the data to be sent
        $.post(yess.ajaxurl, sentdataa, function (rez) { //start of funciton
            alert(rez);

            return false;
        } //end of function
        ,
        'html'); //set the dataType as json, so you will get the parsed data in the callback
    }); // submit end here
});
```

Thanks !

Comment: I wouldn't call it `wp_insert`, it's a very generic name and could cause clashes, try `zeeshan_insert_store_locator` and avoid reusing the Core prefixes for non-core code

Comment: Could you please format your code in a way that it is readable? Line breaks and intending properly, etc. would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX callback method should be outputting something followed by a die() statement.

```
function wp_insert() {
    ..your code
    echo $whatever_your_results_are;
    //
    die();
}
```

I would also recommend against prefixing your custom methods with `wp_`. That should be reserved for WordPress and will cause confusion to other developers - and probably you 6 months down the road :)

Hope this helps

Comment: I am still getting zero I have added that

Comment: what are you returning?

Comment: Thanks everybody my problem is solved I had to change the below line ... below is the corrected version ... thanks everybody who helped me thanks                  add_action( 'wp_ajax_insertfunction', 'insertfunction' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_insertfunction', 'insertfunction');